# What is the difference between the study of evolutionary algorithms and optimization?

Tags: comparison, optimization, evolutionary-algorithms

I have a course named "Evolutionary Algorithms", but our teacher is always mentioning the word "optimization" in his lectures.

I am confused. Is he actually teaching optimization? If yes, why is the name of the course not "Optimization"?

What is the difference between the study of evolutionary algorithms and optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization problems are formally defined by two things:

1. Optimization objective: $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$$
2. List of constraints: $\text{s.t. } x > 0$; $\text{s.t. } x^2 < 100$, ...

Optimization theory as a field deals with variations of such problems. The algorithms that are part of optimization include [gradient descent and variants](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/), the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm), [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) and many more. I would also include evolutionary algorithms as one of the algorithms in this field.

> I am confused. Is he actually teaching optimization? If yes, why is the name of the course not "Optimization"?

Evolutionary algorithms are a subfield of optimization. The name of the course is evolutionary algorithms as you likely don't deal with the other aspects of optimization theory (e.g. the algorithms mentioned above).